# Excel distinct count with conditions

Tags: excel

```
    A            B       C   D  E       F           G           H   I  
115492          2009    10  42  5   90160624    15-Oct-09       WH  5
115492          2009    10  42  5   90160624    15-Oct-09       WH  5
115492          2009    10  42  5   90160624    15-Oct-09       WH  5
115492          2009    10  42  5   90160624    15-Oct-09       WH  5
115481          2009    10  44  6   90170587    30-Oct-09       WH  3
115481          2009    10  44  6   90170587    30-Oct-09       WH  3
115481          2009    10  44  6   90170587    30-Oct-09       WH  3
115481          2009    10  44  6   90170587    30-Oct-09       WH  3
115481          2009    10  44  6   90170587    30-Oct-09       WH  3
115481          2009    10  44  6   90170587    30-Oct-09       WH  3
115481          2009    10  44  6   90170587    30-Oct-09       WH  3
115481          2009    10  44  6   90170587    30-Oct-09       WH  3
115481          2009    10  44  6   90170587    30-Oct-09       WH  3
115520          2009    11  45  5   90174693    5-Nov-09        WH  3
115520          2009    11  45  5   90174693    5-Nov-09        WH  3
115520          2009    11  45  5   90174693    5-Nov-09        WH  3
115520          2009    11  45  5   90174693    5-Nov-09        WH  3
115502          2009    11  46  6   90179821    13-Nov-09       WH  3
115502          2009    11  46  6   90179821    13-Nov-09       WH  3
115502          2009    11  46  6   90179821    13-Nov-09       WH  3
115502          2009    11  46  6   90179821    13-Nov-09       WH  3
115502          2009    11  46  6   90179821    13-Nov-09       WH  3
115502          2009    11  46  6   90179821    13-Nov-09       WH  3
115502          2009    11  46  6   90179821    13-Nov-09       WH  3
115502          2009    11  46  6   90179821    13-Nov-09       WH  3
115502          2009    11  46  6   90179821    13-Nov-09       WH  3
123057          2009    11  46  3   90182107    17-Nov-09       WH  3
123057          2009    11  46  3   90182107    17-Nov-09       WH  3
123057          2009    11  46  3   90182107    17-Nov-09       WH  3
123057          2009    11  46  3   90182107    17-Nov-09       WH  3
123056          2009    11  47  3   90186948    24-Nov-09       WH  3
123056          2009    11  47  3   90186948    24-Nov-09       WH  3
123056          2009    11  47  3   90186948    24-Nov-09       WH  3
123056          2009    11  47  3   90186948    24-Nov-09       WH  3
115506          2009    11  47  3   90186673    24-Nov-09       WH  5
115506          2009    11  47  3   90186673    24-Nov-09       WH  5
115506          2009    11  47  3   90186673    24-Nov-09       WH  5
115506          2009    11  47  3   90186673    24-Nov-09       WH  5
115506          2009    11  47  3   90186673    24-Nov-09       WH  5
115506          2009    11  47  3   90186673    24-Nov-09       WH  5
115506          2009    11  47  3   90186673    24-Nov-09       WH  5
115506          2009    11  47  3   90186673    24-Nov-09       WH  5
115496          2009    11  47  4   90187409    25-Nov-09       WH  3
115496          2009    11  47  4   90187409    25-Nov-09       WH  3
115496          2009    11  47  4   90187409    25-Nov-09       WH  3
115496          2009    11  47  4   90187409    25-Nov-09       WH  3
123058          2009    12  50  5   90198449    10-Dec-09       WH  3
123058          2009    12  50  5   90198449    10-Dec-09       WH  3
123058          2009    12  50  5   90198449    10-Dec-09       WH  3
123058          2009    12  50  5   90198449    10-Dec-09       WH  3
115522          2009    12  50  7   90200094    12-Dec-09       WH  7
115522          2009    12  50  7   90200094    12-Dec-09       WH  7
115522          2009    12  50  7   90200094    12-Dec-09       WH  7
115522          2009    12  50  7   90200094    12-Dec-09       WH  7
115522          2009    12  50  7   90200094    12-Dec-09       WH  7
123059          2009    12  51  6   90203897    18-Dec-09       WH  4
123059          2009    12  51  6   90203897    18-Dec-09       WH  4
123059          2009    12  51  6   90203897    18-Dec-09       WH  4
123059          2009    12  51  6   90203897    18-Dec-09       WH  4
115539          2009    12  51  7   90204074    19-Dec-09       WH  5
115539          2009    12  51  7   90204074    19-Dec-09       WH  5
115539          2009    12  51  7   90204074    19-Dec-09       WH  5
115539          2009    12  51  7   90204074    19-Dec-09       WH  5
115539          2009    12  51  7   90204074    19-Dec-09       WH  5
115539          2009    12  51  7   90204074    19-Dec-09       WH  5
115541          2009    12  51  7   90204389    19-Dec-09       WH  4
115541          2009    12  51  7   90204389    19-Dec-09       WH  4
115541          2009    12  51  7   90204389    19-Dec-09       WH  4
115541          2009    12  51  7   90204389    19-Dec-09       WH  4
115534          2009    12  52  2   90209074    28-Dec-09       WH  5
115534          2009    12  52  2   90209074    28-Dec-09       WH  5
115534          2009    12  52  2   90209074    28-Dec-09       WH  5
115534          2009    12  52  2   90209074    28-Dec-09       WH  5
115534          2009    12  52  2   90209074    28-Dec-09       WH  5
115534          2009    12  52  2   90209074    28-Dec-09       WH  5
```

considering a table above, 
How do I get distinct count of "A" column value where "I" has value "3"?

Comment: do you want an automated solution (formula or vba)? a one shot solution? What do you mean by "distinct count"?

Comment: I need an excel formula... 
distinct count : "A" column has duplicate values, and these duplicates should be considered as one count.

Comment: Thats a shame, this would be very easy to do in VBA :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres an alternative that doesn't rely on unique items in column A being consecutive

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A2:A76,A2:A76)>0,(I2:I76=3)*1,0))
```

Enter as an array formula

Comment: hi, if I need to add more than one condition then should I write something like: 
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A2:A76,A2:A76)>0,(AND(I2:I76=3, J2:J76=2))*1,0))
??

Comment: try `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A2:A76,A2:A76)>0,(I2:I76=3)*(J2:J76=2),0))`

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want a count of unique entries in column 'A' where column 'I' equals 3.

One (imperfect) solution would be:

```
=SUM((A1:A999<>A2:A1000)*(I2:I1000=3))+IF(A1=A2,0,IF(I1=3,1,0))
```

evaluated as an array formula.

Comment: Oh, just that I need to add the `IF` statement to deal with the top row.  Does the trick though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "one shot solution":

- filter column `I` >> http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter01.html
- select whole `A` column
- Excel will display the `SUM` and the `COUNT` values on the bottom right

[EDIT] Btw, here are some [tips](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx) for removing duplicates

**[EDIT] Formula solution**

- Add a formula in Column `J`: `=IF(COUNTIF(A3:$A$1000,A2)>1,0,1)` (this will tell if there is another same value further in the range)
- Drag and drop this formula till the end of your range
- Use a formula like *Chris* suggested ("kindof" because this is not an array formula): `=SUMPRODUCT((I2:I1000=3)*(A2:A1000))`

Comment: This wouldn't exclude duplicates in column A.

Comment: @Chris: yes, but it wasn't clear originally in the OP question. i suggested another solution