# Distinct count with conditions

Tags: excel

I am referring to the following post : [Excel distinct count with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098766/excel-distinct-count-with-conditions)

I would like to do the same thing that has been asked and answered by user Chris Neilsen, however there is a little twist.

```
A                 
sp24679999        
sp24661009        
sp24661003        
sp24660009        
sp24660003        
1231244545        
1231244545       

B
YES
YES
NO
YES
NO
NO
NO
```

I would like to count how many different values there are in column A containing "NO" in column B. The problem here is that there are not only values in column A, but there is also text. Here answer should be **3**

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated
Thank you very much

Comment: Here is what I have so far, but it does NOT include the condition : SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(Data!H2:H9231)>0;MATCH(Data!H2:H9231;Data!H2:H9231;0);""); IF(LEN(Data!H2:H9231)>0;MATCH(Data!H2:H9231;Data!H2:H9231;0);""))>0;1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will be easy to use the `FREQUENCY` formula here because you have text.

Here is a try in another way:

```
{=SUM(IF(B1:B15="NO",IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A15,A1:A15,B1:B15,"NO")>1,1/COUNTIFS(A1:A15,A1:A15,B1:B15,"NO"),1),0))}
```

[EDIT] French version (as the OP has a french version of Excel)

```
=SOMME(SI(B1:B15="NO";SI(NB.SI.ENS(A1:A15;A1:A15;B1:B15;"NO")>1;1/NB.SI.ENS(A1:A15;A1:A15;B1:B15;"NO");1);0))
```

Validate as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The formula will count for a total of 1 each couple of unique in col A / "NO" in col B, and 1 if there is only one couple.

I've tested if on a sample of data.

I hope I didn't mess up my formula translation. Please tell me if anything goes wrong.